# HTML table formatting with rowspans doesn't work

Tags: html, html-table

I want to make table just as shown but without the dot in the 3rd row. When you open the site you can see that there's a dot next to 8 and I want it to be removed, but when I remove it the whole table format destroys itself.

```html
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">7</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td>.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try replacing with `&nbsp;` if you want to keep a character-sized space there (nbsp = non-breaking space)

Comment: The row counts in each column must match. That doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The thing is I need to use only HTML and everything seems to be right as I see it so I don't know what's the issue